# sql join relationship - if an entry is found, then don't select

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 tables : users, roles and roles_users (roles_users is a relational table with 2 columns, user_id and role_id)

A user can have many roles, through the roles_users table.

How can I build a select query that will not select a user, if he has a specific role.

To illustrate :

- a super admin user has the super admin , admin, login and publisher roles.
- an admin user has the admin, login and publisher roles.
- a publisher user has the login and publisher roles.

I want to select all the users that do not have the super admin role.
In other words, if a user has the super admin role, then do not select it.

How can I achieve this in SQL ?

**Edit : Here is the query that worked for me at the end :** (thanks to [András Ottó's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1434734/andras-otto) answer)

```
SELECT DISTINCT(users.id), users.*
FROM users
INNER JOIN roles_users on users.id = roles_users.user_id
INNER JOIN roles ON roles_users.role_id = roles.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT roles_users.user_id FROM roles_users
      WHERE roles_users.user_id = users.id AND roles_users.role_id = 2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Sql Server on in Oracle you can try:

```
SELECT users.*, roles.roleName
FROM users
INNER JOIN roles_users on users.userid = roles_users.userid
INNER JOIN roles ON roles_users.roleID = roles.roleID
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT roles_users.userID FROM roles_users
      WHERE roles_users.userID = users.userid AND roleName = 'super admin')
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/838b0/1).

Comment: The other answers were still giving me the super admin user because there was something missing in the where not exists part...

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

it uses `subquery`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN roles_use b
            on a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE   b.role_id NOT IN
        (
            SELECT role_id
            FROM roles
            WHERE rolename = 'super admin'
        )
```

OR

uses `left join`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    users a
        LEFT JOIN roles_use b
            on a.user_id = b.user_id
        LEFT JOIN roles c
            ON b.role_id = c.role_id AND
               c.roleName = 'super admin'
WHERE   c.role_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `JOIN` to get the solution to your problem....

If you have list of role to restrict, use `NOT IN` in following way:

```
SELECT a.* FROM users a INNER JOIN users_role b ON a.user_id= b.user_id 
INNER JOIN roles c ON b.role_id = c.role_id 
WHERE c.role_name NOT IN ('SUPER ADMIN')
```

If you have one role to restrict, use `!=` in following way:

```
SELECT a.* FROM users a INNER JOIN users_role b ON a.user_id= b.user_id 
INNER JOIN roles c ON b.role_id = c.role_id 
WHERE c.role_name != 'SUPER ADMIN'
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
SELECT  u.*
FROM    users u 
JOIN    roles_users ru
ON      u.user_id=ru.user_id
JOIN    roles r
ON      r.role_id=ru.role_id   
WHERE   rol_name !='Super admin'
```